# Showing a function map to itself

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $ D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1\}$. Fix $ w \in D$ and define $f: \bar{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $$f(z) = \frac{w-z}{1-\bar{w}z}$$
Show the following:

- $f$ maps $D$ to $D$ and $\partial D$ to $\partial D$
- $f$ is bijection on $D$
- $f$ is holomorphic on $D$

can anyone show me or give hint of how to prove them?

My idea for the third bullet is I use the definition of holomorphic

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z_0+z) - f(z_0)}{z}$$ 
to show that the function $f$ is complex differentiable. But for other 2 bullets, I don't know how to do it yet

Comment: for the holomorphic part, I used the $\lim \frac{f(z_0 + z) - f(z_0)}{z}$ to show that it complex differentiable. But, I don't know how to prove the other two.

Comment: That it's holomorphic is easy if you know that polynomials are holomorphic and you also know the quotient rule.  (You do have to check that the one pole is not in $D$.)  That it's bijective on $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ is essentially high-school algebra; that it's bijective on $D$ depends on your first bullet point.  People would probably be more forthcoming if you tell us specifically where you ran into difficulty rather than writing as if you were giving us a homework assignment.

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$and your idea of working directly from the definition of differentiation is also not hard in this case.  But you do still need to check that the pole is not in $D$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Hint for the first bullet: $\lvert 1-\overline{w}\cdot z\rvert^2 - \lvert w-z\rvert^2$.

Comment: Why not just use the quotient rule to show $f$ holomorphic? Have you studied basic properties of linear fractional transformations?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

(1) Show that $|1-\bar{z_1}z_2|^2-|z_1-z_2|^2=(1-|z_1|^2)(1-|z_2|^2)$.

(2) Show that it is bijective on $\bar{\mathbb{C}}$ by finding its inverse.

(3) Use the fact that $(f/g)'=(f'g-fg')/g^2$.